# Comparative dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes, one coming from a database with the following fields:

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| bakarery | 010203040000150 |
| store | 010203040000160 |
| market | 010203040000180 |
| hospital | 010203040000190 |
| bakery | 010203040000200 |

And another dataframe that I need to compare to be able to update the IDs:

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| bakarery | 1020304050 |
| store | 010203040000160 |
| market | 010203040000180 |
| hospital | 3040506070 |
| bakery | 010203040000200 |

I need to create a third dataframe only with the IDs I need to update, looking at the name, if that name updated the ID then I create that dataframe.

How can I do this?

Expected output:

| name | id |
| --- | --- |
| bakarery | 1020304050 |
| hospital | 3040506070 |

Comment: so you want id's present in df1 to be same as in df2 for a new df3

Comment: The dataframe 2 names has updated ids, I create the only with those IDs that need dataframe, the third name the key in this case would be. @DontDownvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming first one is `df1` and second one `df2`:

```py
df2.join(df1, on="name").where(df1["id"] != df2["id"]).show()

+--------+----------+---------------+                                           
|    name|        id|             id|
+--------+----------+---------------+
|bakarery|1020304050|010203040000150|
|hospital|3040506070|010203040000190|
+--------+----------+---------------+
```

or also :

```py
df2.subtract(df1).show()
+--------+----------+                                                           
|    name|        id|
+--------+----------+
|bakarery|1020304050|
|hospital|3040506070|
+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
d = {'bakery':'010203040000150','store':'010203040000160'}
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=d,index=[0])
d1={'bakery':'1020304050','store':'010203040000160'}
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=d1,index=[0])
df3=df1==df2
df4=df2.mask(~df3).fillna(df2)
df4

bakery  store
0   1020304050  010203040000160
```

The above code is executed for a small sample, but it should do the job.

Comment: yeah, understood @Steven

Comment: the expected solution should be in pyspark, not pandas